# How to have vertical line between table cells?

Tags: html, css

In the code below I want to have vertical line between cells, What is the best way to do that? Somethings I tried are giving background color to table but its something same as giving border to table cell, then tried border-left or border-right but it will give one extra line outside cell. Here I want vertical line between cells. Please help.

```css
table tr td {
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this is first cell</td>
    <td>this is second cell</td>
    <td>this is third cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is fouth cell</td>
    <td>this is fifth cell</td>
    <td>this is sixth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: look up first child/last child

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this? This adds a border to every `table tr td` except the last one in the row

```css
table tr td {
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  color: black
}

table tr td:last-of-type {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this is the first cell</td>
    <td>this is the second cell</td>
    <td>this is the third cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is the fourth cell</td>
    <td>this is the fifth cell</td>
    <td>this is the sixth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As mentioned by Daniel A. White - `last-child` also works:

```
table tr td:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: You can also add `table {border-collapse: collapse;}` so you will get lines without space between https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/6/

Answer (score 3):

You can apply CSS border to your `td` and add `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` to remove the gap between `td`

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>this is first cell</td>
    <td>this is second cell</td>
    <td>this is third cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is fouth cell</td>
    <td>this is fifth cell</td>
    <td>this is sixth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: black;
}
table tr td{
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
table tr td:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/1ehubox9/

Answer (score 1):

```
table tr td {
   border-right: 1px solid black;
}
table tr td:nth-child(3n){
    border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a border to the right of the cells and a border to the left of the table should do it:

```css
table tr td {
  border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
  color: black
}

table {
  border-left: 1px solid #dedede;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this is first cell</td>
    <td>this is second cell</td>
    <td>this is third cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is fouth cell</td>
    <td>this is fifth cell</td>
    <td>this is sixth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: as i said vertical line between cells not outside.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table tr td+td {
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  color: black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this is first cell</td>
    <td>this is second cell</td>
    <td>this is third cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is fouth cell</td>
    <td>this is fifth cell</td>
    <td>this is sixth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```